# JavaScript minification workflow with Maven

Tags: java, javascript, maven, war, gruntjs

I am wondering about any "best practices" to integrate a "modern JavaScript build workflow" into a Maven build that produces a WAR artifact.

I have found several maven plugins that handle concatenation and minification:

- WRO4J: https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/wiki/MavenPlugin
- Minify Maven Plugin: https://github.com/samaxes/minify-maven-plugin
- YUI: http://alchim.sourceforge.net/yuicompressor-maven-plugin/

However I am still missing how they fit into a full build workflow, since I think it is mandatory to be able to switch concatenation/minification on and off:

For development I want to build a WAR that does not contain the concatenated/minified resources so that I can conveniently debug. For a production build I want to produce a WAR that contains the concatenated/minified resources.

Additionally for the production build I then have to "rewrite" the script URLs in my html to point to the concatenate/minified version(s) of the script(s).

In the JavaScript world I would use Grunt with different grunt tasks (uglify, usemin) to achieve the above workflow. How can I achieve the same in a Maven build?

Comment: I know that this is an old thread, I got here in one of my searches in a complete different matter. So I read the question and I think that the answer provided by @JamesMurphy is ok, regarding the second part you mention in your comment `struggling with how can I "rewrite" my HTML so that it uses the non-minified or the minified JavaScript`, why do you need to use different files at all? I would use in my html `someScritp.js` and in for a development it would be non-minified and for production it would be minified. Would that be a good solution?

Comment: @JorgeCampos The standard optimization steps for a modern frontend project are minification, concatenation/bundling and cache-busting. For development you want fine-grained files while in productions you want only very few files containing all your assets (JS, CSS ...). Optimizing many files into few files is called *concatenation* or *bundling*. Typically you also want to "cache-bust" the files by adding a hash to the filename. These new files have then to be referenced as `<script>`-tags in your html. In recent projects I am using *WebPack*, skipping Maven integration entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the info and heads up @jbandi :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned Grunt, have you considered calling Grunt tasks directly from your Maven build? It's not a perfect solution, but it gives you some more options without relying on Maven plugins.
http://addyosmani.com/blog/making-maven-grunt/

Also, this SO topic:  [Javascript web app and Java server, build all in Maven or use Grunt for web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15406977/1024571)

Comment: Nice choice. Grunt would probably solve the problem since you can just run that grunt task tied with a maven goal.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to run maven with different profiles so you can minify js scripts for a production build but build it locally with a different profile for the purposes of debugging.

There's more information about this on [Maven's build profile page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using Maven profiles solves the first part of my question: How to switch the minification on and off for different builds. However I am still struggling with how can I "rewrite" my HTML so that it uses the non-minified or the minified JavaScript. Is there another Maven plugin for that?

Comment: Hi again, no problem. It looks like the answer was already found in another Stack Overflow question... [How do you automate javascript minification for your java web applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379856/how-do-you-automate-javascript-minification-for-your-java-web-applications). It looks like you can use YUICompressor ant target. You can use the maven-antrun-plugin to execute an ant goal at whatever point you want in your Maven build. I think that should be enough for you to do what you want.

Comment: In answer to your question, you could in theory write a bash script that scans all your HTML files and replaces the *.js files with *.min.js if they are located in the same directory. Although I don't know if there is anything out-of-the-box that will do this for it. It's potentially a bit bespoke so unfortunately you may have to write this yourself.

Comment: If you're using a scripting language like PHP or even JSPs you may be able to write a method that checks if there is a setting to enable the build to use minified js. In which case, then it can precede the *.js with *.min.js as required.

Comment: @ Dropkick: Thanks for your comments. I am still hoping that there is something more mature out there that I have not found yet ... I just think that this should be a standard problem that should have a standard solution...