# How can I minimize (on-the-fly) dynamically generated CSS inside servlet?

Tags: java, css, tomcat, servlets, jawr

My Tomcat servlet generate CSS from several patterns dynamically.

After CSS manipulations done, servlet return it.

I want minimize generated CSS.

What way I can minimize CSS before response?

- Java routines
- External library
- Other

Sample of GET handler:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

StringBuilder cssContent = new StringBuilder();

/* Some CSS manipulations */

/* Now cssContent contain generated CSS. Lets return it. */

/* Minimize before response!!! - How? */

response.setContentType("text/css");
response.setStatus(200);
response.getWriter().write(cssContent.toString());

}
```

Comment: "_Which library I can use_" == off topic on this site.

Comment: https://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/ has worked well for me in the past for static compressions.  I've not used it dynamically but it is a Java program and should be able to be integrated into the servlet or a filter.

Comment: The following post from StackOverflow summarizes quite a few methods - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379856/how-do-you-automate-javascript-minification-for-your-java-web-applications