# Integrating JS and CSS minimizing with ThymeLeaf and SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot project which hosts several APIs and some simple web pages.
My project is built using Maven by Jenkins.

I'm using ThymeLeaf as my HTML templating tool for the few web pages that I have.
But I'm having issues integrating a tool to minimize my JS and CSS files.

I would like to have my JS and CSS files as full fat files in my src directory but upon compilation, I would like to have the JS and CSS files minimized and references to the full/fat files updated in the thymeleaf html files.

**Edit**

To those marking my question down and voting to close it, why not post a comment explaining why?

This is a valid request and if you don't know the answer, go find another question to answer to build up your rep points.

Comment: Please remove the "This is a valid request and if you don't know the answer, go find another question to answer to build up your rep points." from the question text. It can see it as a (questionable) comment, but it is certainly not part of the question.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553292/javascript-minification-workflow-with-maven and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379856/how-do-you-automate-javascript-minification-for-your-java-web-applications - your question may already be answered. What have you tried?